# Creating many processes using fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to create processes using the system function `fork()`. I want to manage a specific structure of processes, like a binary tree.

Namely, I would like to have a root (main) process and create for example three children. Then each child creates another three children etc.

I have written this code:

```
pid_t pid;
int counter_node = 0;           //count the childs-nodes

while(counter_node < num_mergers)          //num_mergers = max childs from cmd
{
            pid = fork();
            if(pid > 0)                     //parent process
            {
                    write(1,"Just born a child\n",18);
                    counter_node++;
            }
            else if(!pid)                   //child process
            {
                break;
            }
}
```

How can I make the birth childs by childs scalable?

Comment: What's the base case for this "recursion"?

Comment: I don't think the recursion to be honest.I trying with while loop..mmmm.i will get an effort..

Comment: The first base case of recursion is the number of childs,which must be specific,and second the depth of tree,also must be specific,and is argument from cmd.Also i wonder if i have to keep the id of processes in a array or not??